# uncategorized SQLException for SQL delete query

Tags: java, sql, spring

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested
>   exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column
>   type\",\"error\":\"UncategorizedSQLException\"}"}

My case: 
In our DB one user will have one Id but this one Id can can have multiple values. for example I have one userId, for my userID I have 10 health records. so I have to delete these 10 health records in one shot. so I'm passing userId and List for values(data type is Number). raw query works but when I go through java code it is giving Invalid column exception. any suggestions?

Java Implementation method is to make this call is

```
@Override
public void deleteSampleValue(BiometricPkDTO biometricPkDTO){
    update(deleteSampleValueSql,log,biometricPkDTO.getSeriesPk(),biometricPkDTO.getSamplePks());
}
```

and the SQL query I added in resource folder is

delete from bio_sample
where BIO_SERIES_PK = ?
and BIO_SAMPLE_PK in (?)

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: sure. Java Implementation method is  @Override
 public void deleteSampleValue(BiometricPkDTO biometricPkDTO){
  update(deleteSampleValueSql,log,biometricPkDTO.getSeriesPk(),biometricPkDTO.getSamplePks());
 } and the SQL Query I added in resource folder is delete from bio_sample
where BIO_SERIES_PK = ?
and BIO_SAMPLE_PK in (?)

Comment: I'd add this and the stack trace to the question.

Comment: These type of errors do happen when there is a mismatch between IN/OUT parameters, as declared in your Stored Procedures/Queries and in your Java code. I think the problem is with the datatypes of the data you are passing

Comment: The Datatype is Number(5,0) and I'm passing List<long>. Is this causing an issue

Answer (score 0):

As I'm performing multiple deletes action for one specific Id, it is suggested to use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource()). Instantiating MapSqlParameterSource object and by using the reference variable pass the inputs to sql query. The final Dao implementation method looks like:

@Override
    public void deleteSample(BiometricPkDTO biometricPkDTO){

```
    MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameterSource.addValue("seriesPk",biometricPkDTO.getSeriesPk());
    parameterSource.addValue("samplePks", biometricPkDTO.getSamplePks());

    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(deleteSampleSql,parameterSource);
}
```